# Android BroadcastReceiver's onReceive not called when internet is OFF in redmi 2

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

The broadcast receiver does not work when my internet connection is off, but its working fine when my internet is connected.

I have enabled auto start in the security settings for my app. I have also restarted Redmi / note3, and in some redmi2 it is working fine.

Either its offline or online but in some redmi2 phone its completely not working

```
    public void timerTask(final  Context ctx){
     Log.e("calling...","timer...");
     Timer t= new Timer();
     t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             try {
                 Log.e("in try","catch...");
                 ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                 /*if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                         connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)*/
                 NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                 if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable()){
                     //we are connected to a network
                     Log.e("timeTask","executing...");
                     try{my_details = new Database_Check_In_Helper(ctx);}catch (NullPointerException npe){npe.printStackTrace();}
                     Cursor res = my_details.call_log1();
                   //  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                     while (res.moveToNext()) {
                         String phNum = res.getString(0);
                         String callType = res.getString(1);
                         String callDate = res.getString(2);
                         String callDuration = res.getString(3);
                         String phoneId = res.getString(4);
                         // String dtStart = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z";
                        /* Date date = null;
                         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
                         try {

                             date = format.parse(callDate);
                             Log.e("datefor",""+date);
                             *//*System.out.println(date);*//*
                         } catch (ParseException e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }*/

                         DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
                         Date date=null;
                         try {
                             date = (Date) formatter.parse(callDate);

                             Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                             cal.setTime(date);
                             String formatedDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                         Log.e("formatedDate",""+formatedDate);
                         }catch (ParseException pe){pe.printStackTrace();}

                        /* SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new   SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

                         Date d1 = null;
                         try{
                             d1 = sdf3.parse(callDate);

                         }catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }*/


                         Log.e("data are",phNum+" "+callType+" "+date+" "+callDuration+"  "+phoneId);
                         String url = "http://www.rentmystay.com/m/call_tracking_log";
                         ServiceNetworkConnection snc = new ServiceNetworkConnection(phNum, callType, date, callDuration, phoneId);
                         snc.execute(url);
                      }
                 }else{


                     Log.e("internet","not connected");
                 }

             }catch (NullPointerException npe){
                 Log.e("npe ","come under excep");
                 npe.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     },0,5000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently while checking internet connection you should check isConnected() method of activeNetwork.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        // Network Active
    }else{
        // Network Inactive
    }
```

Comment: I tried isConnected() method also, but there is no use. But the problem is same